# simple AJAX JQuery example gives me 500 internal server error

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-security

hi i'm working in a spring mvc project and i'm getting this error when i hit the button in my form

```
500 (Internal Server Error)                                    jquery.min.js:6
x.ajaxTransport.x.support.cors.e.crossDomain.send  jquery.min.js:6 
x.extend.ajax                                      AddUser:19 
doAjaxPost                                         AddUser:41 
onclick
```

i'm trying to do a simple AJAX JQuery example that adds users to a list but i get that error when i press the add button in my form

this is my controller class:

```
@Controller
public class UserListController {

 private List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();

     @RequestMapping(value="AddUser",method=RequestMethod.GET)
     public String showForm(){

         return "AddUser";
     }

     @RequestMapping(value="AddUser",method=RequestMethod.POST)
     public @ResponseBody String addUser(@ModelAttribute(value="user") User user, BindingResult result ) 
     {
         String returnText;

         if(!result.hasErrors())
         {
             userList.add(user);
             returnText = "User has been added to the list. Total number of users are " + userList.size();

         }
         else
         {
             returnText = "Sorry, an error has occur. User has not been added to list.";
         }

         return returnText;
     }

     @RequestMapping(value="ShowUsers")
     public String showUsers(ModelMap model) 
     {
         model.addAttribute("Users", userList);

         return "ShowUsers";
     }
```

}

and this is my AddUser.jsp page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Add Users using ajax</title>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- <script src="resources/js/libs/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script> -->

        <script type="text/javascript">

        function doAjaxPost() {
        // get the form values
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var education = $('#education').val();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "AddUser",
        data: "name=" + name + "&education=" + education,
        success: function(response){
        // we have the response
        $('#info').html(response);
        $('#name').val('');
        $('#education').val('');
        },
        error: function(e){
        alert('Error: ' + e);
        }
        });
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Add Users using Ajax ........</h1>
        <table>
            <tr><td>Enter your name : </td><td> <input type="text" id="name"><br/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Education : </td><td> <input type="text" id="education"><br/></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Add Users" onclick="doAjaxPost()"><br/></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><div id="info" style="color: green;"></div></td></tr>
        </table>
        <a href="/views/ShowUsers">Show All Users</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my MvcConfiguration class since i'm using a java based configuration and not using XML

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "controllers" })
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
     @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
       registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
       configurer.enable();
    }

//  JSP VIEW-RESOLVER
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
       InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
       bean.setOrder(2);
       bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
       bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
       return bean;
    }
}
```

EDIT: i starter a new project just for the sake of trying to know what error i'm having, i delete spring secuirty in my application, but i still can figure out whats wrong.

1) i actually dont delete spring security i just starte a new project to try to solve my url problem

2) i change my controllers and the URL attribute in my ajax script

new RequestMapping controllers:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="AddUser",method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

i deleted the "/" in the value="AddUser"

i dont have a "/" in any of my controllers if put a "/" in the controllers i have the same 500 Internal server error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be because of the CSRF protection which is enabled by default in Java configuration. Try in your configuration...

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        // ...
        .csrf().disable();
}
```

Let me know if this works.

EDIT**

To include CSRF token in AJAX request, if you are using JSON, you need to put it on the http header. Sample JSP example typically would be...

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
</head>
```

Then in your javascript call, get this parameters and add it to XMLHttpRequest's header.

Hope this helps.

[Further reading](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf)

Comment: i put this at the end of my spring security congifuration class  `.and()
      .csrf().disable();` and i tried but it know gives a 404 error

Comment: Good news. Now you are posting from Ajax with ` url: "views/AddUser"`. Where is the controller mapping for that? I can only see /AddUser in Controller.

Comment: i updated the ajax script with this `URL : AddUser` and in the controllers iupdated the mapping of the controller from `value="/AddUser"` to `value="AddUser"` now it gives me `500 (internal server error)`

Comment: It should be /AddUser I believe. Now it is a generic error and you have to see what is the URL it is posting to exactly etc. But I believe your primary issue is solved.

Comment: kinda but i dont want to disable my csrf tokken is there another way to do this without having to disable the csrf tokken

Comment: If you are planning to use the CSRF token, you have to get and include it on http headers for ajax calls. You can't simply keep it enabled. If you want, I can provide some pointers.

Comment: Please see my edit. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70648/discussion-between-aninda-bhattacharyya-and-stackuser2000).

Comment: I am not following your edits. You mentioned couple of points...1. You wanted to use CSRF and I provided you some strategy. I am not seeing that edit or disabling CSRF. 2. I told you to recheck your URL from AddUser to /AddUser, did it help? Sorry, but please don't deviate and use proper edits.

Comment: i edited again my question, thanks for the csrf strategy i'm going to use it later but i'm still having that 500 internal server error, i already checked my URL again

Comment: What URL you are using now? Is it AddUser or /AddUser from javascript?

Comment: i'm using AddUser in everything, in the request mapping and in my javascript

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70662/discussion-between-aninda-bhattacharyya-and-stackuser2000).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i had to add the below dependency to my pom
`<dependency> <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId> <artifactId>gson</artifactId> <version>2.2.2</version> </dependency>`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).